# MYSQL Select Statment with Modification to tuple values

Tags: sql, mysql, select

I have the following table:

```
bar_id, bar_name, subscription_id_fk, sub_name
```

eg:

```
1, Hard Rock, 2, Gold
2, TGIF, 1, Free
```

Now I need and SQL to extract this table, but where sub_name = Gold, I need to double the subscription_id_fk.

Can you please help
?

Edit:
I need this value to be only changed in the result of the SQL statment

Comment: Take a look at Vitalii's answer and see if that is what you meant. In another words: did you mean a) to return only rows where sub_name = 'Gold' (and return subscription_id_fk * 2) or b) subscription_id_fk for all rows, but in case sub_name = 'Gold' return the double value?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you looking for something as simple as

```
SELECT (subscription_id_fk * 2) as double_sif
FROM table
WHERE sub_name = 'Gold'
```

As you accepted this answer a few comments

- SELECT statements never change anything in the database, for that you need UPDATE, INSERT or DELETE (at least read [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL) article on SQL)
- the name of the field suggests that it is a [foreign key](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Foreign_key) to another table and even though it is possible, normally multiplying keys don't make any sense

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT IF(sub_name = 'Gold', subscription_id_fk * 2, subscription_id_fk) as fk 
FROM my_table
```

Comment: Ok, thats much simpler than my approach :-)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe I don't understand the question, but this looks like a simple update to me:

`UPDATE table 
SET subscription_id_fk = (subscription_id_fk * 2) 
WHERE sub_name = "Gold"`

Comment: I would not say this would change it only in the results but only in the database. :)

Comment: Oh - I havent seen the "only in the result" part - it was edited after me :)

Answer (score 0):

[This](http://www.java2s.com/Code/SQL/Function/Docalculationinselectclause.htm) may help you.

So, According to the link you try,

`select subscription_id_fk * 2 from table where sub_name = 'Gold'`

I hadn't try it practically.I just find it on internet. So, Try it.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, if you need all rows, but only "Gold"-ones with doubled keys, you could use

`SELECT 
    GREATEST(t.subscription_id_fk, IFNULL(t2.subscription_id_fk,0)) AS subscription_id_fk, 
    bar_id, 
    bar_name, 
    sub_name
FROM table AS t
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT (subscription_id_fk * 2) AS subscription_id_fk, 
        id 
    FROM table t2 
    WHERE sub_name ="Gold") AS t2
ON (t.id = t2.id)`